# Meteor for non-internet mobile app

Tags: meteor

I am developing a mobile app for iOS, Android, Windows mobile in Javascript and try to select in between Meteor and Backbone. The app will not include internet connectivity functionality. This app needs to store data on the device, not on a remote server.

I am a newbie in Meteor and have some experience with Backbone, and I am a developer with a strong inclination to having a one tool, ok least minimum number of tools, for deploying to every platform.

I need to write my app in a single code base, and deploy to 3 platforms iOS Android, Windows Mobile.

The Reactive nature and package management of the Meteor attracts me to itself from Backbone.

Is Meteor a suitable tool for developing non-internet connecting mobile apps for those platforms iOS Android, Windows Phone?

Comment: I have made some little initial efforts on the thing I want to succeed. I have used the counter that meteor creates initially when meteor create projectName issued. I have changed the Sessionrelated set and gets by localStorageset and gets, and because Meteor is not reactive against it, I have added code to set innerHTML in the related part of the dom. I have also commented out the if (Meteor.isServer) {} code. after adding iOS platform, meteor run iOS starts project listens at localhost:3000 and start simulator. App on simulator works even I close the server from Terminal.

Comment: Is that viable approach, or Meteor is not a good fit for that?

Comment: the Cordova-build created by Meteor contains all the public assets in the www folder which is accessible even offline. So yes, Meteor is OK for non-internet app, maybe you can call Meteor.disconnect() on start up so it won't even use any bandwidth?

Comment: By the way what are the web.browser and web.cordova folders in the builds. I can find a www dir in iOS but I cannot find a www in android, where is it?

Comment: api.addFiles('both.html','client');
api.addFiles('b.html','web.browser');
api.addFiles('c.html','web.cordova');
api.addFiles('both.txt','client',{isAsset:true});
api.addFiles('b.txt','web.browser',{isAsset:true});
api.addFiles('c.txt','web.cordova',{isAsset:true});

when you call meteor build from console:
1) The both.html and both.txt will get bundled into the www.browser and www.cordova folder
2) The b.html and b.txt are in the www.browser
3) The c.html and c.txt are in the www.cordova

Comment: Anything in the www.cordova folder are available in your app, so both.html, both.txt and c.html and c.txt are in your app offline. You access both.txt and c.txt via /packages/<your package name>/c.txt

Comment: By separating into web.browser and web.cordova, you can have 1 server serving two different client versions. For example, if people come to yourdomain.com from a browser, you show them b.html. But if they access your site from your app, c.html is shown. Even though you focus on offline app, you can still take advantage of the hot code push/reload from Meteor

Comment: Is `isAsset` a new optional argument. I could not find it in the [full api](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_addFiles).

Comment: Now I have located the www folders each in the builds for android and iOS, once I have supposed it was in the bundle folder, which includes main.js, and programs folder includes server, web.browser, and web.cordova. And they seem to have similar files as web.cordova folder, which is expected according to your explanations to be exactly the same.

I have two more things in the bundle/, a server folder and a star.json file, other than the README. What are those?

Comment: try opening the two files using a text editor, they are quite self-explanatory

Comment: sorry :) thanks that was just asked impulsively by me as if I was in a chat. that was not the case.