# Can meteor build a fully offline, static html5 app?

Tags: meteor, static, offline

I was searching for weeks now to find a way to get meteor "export" static html pages into a folder. I want to create an app that fits onto an USB stick and can be called from that by just opening one *index.html* file locally, without the need of a "server".

What I know until now is that you can easily tell meteor [to be offline just by "Meteor.disconnect()"](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Building_for_the_client_only). But this does not solve the issue needing the app locally. What I need is, ideally, placing everything into one folder (with subfolders for images, js, css etc.) The pages should all be loaded "dynamically" by javascript. But I can't find out how to do this.
```
This would be the directory/file structure for my project:

```
data
  main.css
  main.js
  images
     person.jpg
     blah.jpg
index.html
```

This *index.html* should load all the js needed to work. The project consists of approx. 20, completely static, pages. I need no database, I need no serber, as all content is predefined.

Is this possible with meteor?
I had a try with brunch/jade as well, but couldn't solve it neither (I just solved it now having ~20 static **separate html pages**, which is NOT what I need. I just want ONE html page that includes all the content as "single page app". And I can't find anything that helps me really.

Stackoverflow and other pages that have NOT answered this qustion:

- https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data
- [How can Meteor apps work offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135606/how-can-meteor-apps-work-offline)
- http://devel-docs.meteor.com/#appcache

Please tell me that this is possible. And if not with meteor, can this be done with another framework (preferably using jade as template language)?

Comment: Meteor is a full-stack development framework, which means it uses a server, a database, and a client (or hopefully many clients). It sounds fairly weird to want to use Meteor without a server, or a database... I think what you should do is list the features of Meteor you want to extract (like, Spacebars) and try to use them locally.

Comment: @PeppeL-G, this *exactly* what I searched for, thanks. I don't know why I didn't find this question there. Thanks again.