# Meteorjs, cordova and local mongodb (online & offline mode)

Tags: android, mongodb, cordova, meteor

I have a question about meteorjs and cordova mobile app development: will mongodb work locally on my mobile app (built with meteorjs and cordova) even if I turn internet connection off ?

My app will require only locally stored data (but need more space than localstorage provides) and I'm not sure how Meteorjs-cordova apps works after compilation to mobile (android & iOS) - does it have its own MongoDB instance inside it?

And if yes, is it possible to run it in offline mode?

Scenario:

internet connection is needed only on 1st run to download data, next time You can load everything locally and don't need to be connected to the internet.

Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mobile app won't have an exact MongoDB instance on it, but you can use [minimongo](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases) to store data in-memory on the client-side. So if you pull data from your server MongoDB instance, it'll be stored in minimongo until your app is closed. The data isn't persistent so you'll need something like [this package](https://atmospherejs.com/frozeman/persistent-minimongo) to save data between launches.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135606/how-can-meteor-apps-work-offline) for more information

Comment: so I'm gonna need internet connection on every app start?

Comment: In order for any data to be loaded you will need to unless you have persistent storage. You can also take a look at [GroundDB](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db) though I haven't used it before.